# How to update an older iOS app version when a newer one is already out?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, versioning

Let’s imagine I have an iOS app. In version 2.0, I added a bunch of new features, but to implement them, I had to drop support for an older iOS version which is still in heavy use (remember, it’s a hypothetical scenario).

Later, I discovered a super critical bug in version 1.0 of my app that needs to be patched.

**What are my options in terms of distribution?**

It seems that it’s not possible to release version 1.0.1 if version 2.0 is already on the App Store. Adding back support for the older iOS version and fixing the bug in 2.0.1 is not feasible because that would require removal of the new features.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re hosed, for a reason you didn’t mention. You can only submit a new version using Xcode 11. So you are forced to link against iOS 13. You can’t use an old Xcode and an old iOS version: they won’t accept it.

Comment: @matt You’re correct regarding old Xcode versions. But that’s not the case. In my scenario, the older iOS version is still supported by the latest Xcode (think of iOS 8 in Xcode 11).

Comment: Yes but you must still link against iOS 13. So you cannot submit a version that your current users of 2.0 cannot download.

Comment: @matt Aren’t app versions compared by their numbers? I’m pretty sure if you installed version 2.0 from TestFlight or via cable, and then 1.0.1 came out on the App Store, you wouldn’t see 1.0.1 in Updates.

Comment: You cannot submit 1.0.1 after you have submitted 2.0. And anyway my prior point holds. Whatever you submit now, your 2.0 users will download it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that I can’t think of a way you could submit a version that updates version 1 without letting your version 2 users download it. So if you want to update version 1 you will just have to bite the bullet and meld your versions together. Use availability so that the new features are not present for your version 1 users.

Comment: Here’s the comment I wrote just seconds ago on the original question: Aren’t app versions compared by their numbers? I’m pretty sure if you installed version 2.0 from TestFlight or via cable, and then 1.0.1 came out on the App Store, you wouldn’t see 1.0.1 in Updates.